# Javascript fn has 2 arguments when called but only 1 parameter when declared?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I don't understand why this works:

```
function doSomething(a) {
    b = a + doSomethingElse( a * 2 );

    console.log( b * 3 );
}

function doSomethingElse(a) {
    return a - 1;
}

var b;

doSomething( 2 ); // 15
```

How is it that the doSomethingElse inside the doSomething fn can be passing (a * 2) as arguments //line 2// since when doSomethingElse was declared it only takes one parameter?
What the heck is going on here? Can someone explain the order in which this whole thing runs?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not passing two arguments. You are passing the result of the expression `a * 2`, a single argument.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question is really unclear. `doSomethingElse( a * 2 )` passes **one** argument to `doSomethingElse`: The result of computing the expression `a * 2`.

Comment: On the other hand it's okay to pass more arguments than "declared". Those can be accessed through the `arguments` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a * 2` is only one argument. It's whatever the value of `a` is, multiplied by 2.

It would be the same as doing this:

```
function doSomething(a) {
    var c = a * 2;
    b = a + doSomethingElse( c );

    console.log( b * 3 );
}
```

Arguments are separated (in ES5) by a comma. However, you can pass expressions as a single argument, since they result in one value.

Comment: Expressions *always* result in a single value, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder correct, I was just thinking weird cases where you might use an ES6 spread operator as part of the expression (for example, if the result of the expression is an array and you spread it, then it would result in multiple arguments)

Comment: :-) That's why `...` isn't an operator. To be an operator, it would have to have a single result. Rest and spread are syntax, not operators, just like the `()` in a `for` loop aren't the parenthesis operator, just syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the clarification, learning something new every day ;)

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE